# Can't migrate to AndroidX: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed

Tags: android-studio-3.0, androidx

Android Studio 3.2. Gradle 4.6

In my **gradle.properties**:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I want to migrate to AndroidX.
So in menu select

```
Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX
```

Studio replace many of my resources to `androidx...`
Nice.
But when I build project I get error:

```
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  Output:  D:\dev\MyProject\\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1614: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/mode' with config ''.
  D:\dev\MyProject\\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1614: error: resource previously defined here.

  Command: C:\Users\Alexei\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\1140ed5d6b762801720aa38b75493b72\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
          -o \
          D:\dev\MyProject\\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
          D:\dev\MyProject\\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\Users\Alexei\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-swipe-reveal-layout-1.4.1.aar\9897ef13e78d1b3a157ca2f1633442ed\res\values\values.xml:3:5-414: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/mode' with config ''.
```

Comment: Can you post the line:  D:\dev\MyProject\\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1614 ?

Comment: In file: d:\dev\myProject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml - line 1614: <declare-styleable name="SwipeRevealLayout"><attr name="dragEdge"><flag name="left" value="1"/><flag name="right" value="2"/><flag name="top" value="4"/><flag name="bottom" value="8"/></attr><attr name="mode"><enum name="normal" value="0"/><enum name="same_level" value="1"/></attr><attr format="integer" name="flingVelocity"/><attr format="dimension" name="minDistRequestDisallowParent"/></declare-styleable>

Comment: same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978229/android-resource-compilation-failed-error-duplicate-value-for-resource-attr-o